# translate GRIB product on bounding box

Tags: georeferencing, extents, grib

I'm in troubles with the projection of a GRIB product. I have a Cloud mask image and I want georeferencing it with GDAL. I need to pass through gdal_translate before, since i need to fix the bounding box, but i don't know this box. The product is EO:EUM:DAT:MSG:CLM on Eumetsat product navigator.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make sure to order simple grib data, `grib with headers` can not be read with GDAL.**

`gdalinfo` reports the following on a sample file:

```
Driver: GRIB/GRIdded Binary (.grb)
Files: msg3.grb
Size is 3712, 3712
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["Coordinate System imported from GRIB file",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["Spheroid imported from GRIB file",6378140,298.2529810614917]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Geostationary_Satellite"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["satellite_height",35785831],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0]]
Origin = (-5570248.477582973400000,5570248.477582973400000)
Pixel Size = (3000.403165948275700,-3000.403165948275700)
```

It is in a Geostationary projection showing a filled circle, and should be reprojected for further use with gdalwarp:

`gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:4326 msg3.grb out.tif`

You will get a lot of tolerance condition error for points that are outside of the earth.

The reprojected file can be used with other GIS data:

[image]

Note that there are still artefacts in the edges of the original image.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have this:

```
    Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
    Files: CLM_201410281015.tiff
           CLM_201410281015.tiff.aux.xml
    Size is 3712, 3712
    Coordinate System is `'
    Image Structure Metadata:
      INTERLEAVE=BAND
    Corner Coordinates:
    Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
    Lower Left  (    0.0, 3712.0)
    Upper Right ( 3712.0,    0.0)
    Lower Right ( 3712.0, 3712.0)
    Center      ( 1856.0, 1856.0)
    Band 1 Block=3712x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
      Min=0.000 Max=254.000 
      Minimum=0.000, Maximum=254.000, Mean=137.817, StdDev=78.068
      NoData Value=255
      Metadata:
        STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=254
        STATISTICS_MEAN=137.81703083625
        STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
        STATISTICS_STDDEV=78.067587646237
```

Comment: That's not a grib file. Where did you get it from? Maybe a tfw file is missing.

Comment: yes, it's a tiff from grib.